# When and will it be another ubuntu version soon?

Tags: updates

Will it come out a new version of ubuntu?

And when can we expect somthing new?

saw that linux mint has come out with some new features :)

Comment: @JorgeCastro I am not sure that is really a duplicate. I feel the OP is asking for the time, rather than the full details.

Comment: The next release will be Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Thar. The exact release date is not known yet but It will be released in April; [see here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Answer (score 3):

Generally each April and October there will be a new version. See the list of releases [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

Of course the upcomming version, Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, will have lots of new features, but maybe a little less than you expect: Ubuntu 14.04 will be a so called LTS version, so the focus lays rather on stability than on new features.

Answer (score 2):

A new version of Ubuntu comes every April and October. The Ubuntu versions are related to these dates.

> *Example :*
>   Ubuntu **13**. **10** : **10th** month of the **13th** year = October 2013.

LTS versions (Long Term Support) come every two years. Last version was 12.04, so next will be 14.04 (meaning April 2014).

---

Linux Mint is a modified version of Ubuntu, that's why it comes *after* Ubuntu, they need time to modify Ubuntu and test if everything works well. Linux Mint 16 is based on Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu comes out with a new version every 6 months. The version numbers are in the YY:MM format, thus the reason Ubuntu version are always the year and then 04 or 10 (13.10, 14.04).

As for the next version to come out, it will be 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr, the newest Long Term Support version, so you can download the official ISO in April (4th month). LTS versions are supported for much longer and tend to be more stable than the newest version (currently 13.10), but also tend to lack some of the newest features.

New LTS versions come out every 2 years, the current LTS release is 12.04 LTS, from 2012. You can read about the release here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases and the release schedule here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/08/ubuntu-14-04-lts-release-schedule

Answer (score 1):

In April. Just so you know the version numbers of Ubuntu indicate when they are released 12.**04** is released in April (the fourth month), 12.**10** in October (the tenth month). So every six months there is a new release.